# PHP Uncaught com_exception: Parameter 0: Type Mismatch

Tags: php, com, osisoft

I have a function `GetPoints` from COM Object

```
/* DISPID=21 */
/* VT_PTR [26] */
function GetPoints( 
/* VT_BSTR [8] [in] */ $WhereClause, 
/* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29] */ &$pAsynchStatus )
```

When I call the function :

```
$this->PIserver->GetPoints((string) "tag = 'P260*'")
```

I get a `com_exception`:

> Uncaught com_exception: Parameter 0: Type Mismatch

What can I do to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the PI SDK, which is now a legacy product.  Furthermore you need to deal with COM which error codes and types errors are quite cryptic.

I have never used it, but I'd recommend having a look at [PHP:DOTNET](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.dotnet.php), then install the **AF SDK** that is available in the [AF Client](https://www.google.com/search?q=osisoft%20af%20client&oq=osisoft%20af%20client&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1980j0j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  You'll be able to find much better examples and do more things with the AF SDK than the PI SDK.  [AF SDK Documentation](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/html/1a02af4c-1bec-4804-a9ef-3c7300f5e2fc.htm), [Online course to learn PI AF SDK](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/community/Learn-PI).